# Delete row if column value is #N/V

Tags: excel, vba

I was just wondering if anybody can help me with cell's value.
I am trying to delete the entire row if the value of the cell in column A is `#N/V`. I tried almost everything. Here is my code:

```
For Each ws In Sheets(Array("List"))
   lastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
   For i = 1 To lastRow
      If ws.Cells(i, 1).Text = "#N/V" Then
         ws.Cells(i).Delete
      End If
   Next i
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each ws In Sheets(Array("List"))
        lastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        For i = 1 To lastRow
          If ws.Cells(i, 1).Text = "#N/V" Then
             ws.Cells(i,1).entirerow.Delete
             i = i - 1
          End If
        Next i
Next
```

Suggestion of @Grade'Eh'Bacon:

```
For Each ws In Sheets(Array("List"))
        lastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        For i = lastrow To 1 step -1
          If ws.Cells(i, 1).Text = "#N/V" Then
             ws.Cells(i,1).entirerow.Delete

          End If
        Next i
Next
```

Using the Autofilterfunction:

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Range("A1:A1")
    .select
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
      .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="#N/V"
      .Range("A1:A" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End With
```

Comment: I suggest you edit to make i go backwords, ie: 'For i = lastRow to 1 Step -1'; because otherwise deleting a row will skip the "next row", because all following row #s will go down by 1 and at the same time the counter will go up by 1.

Comment: I thought about that in the first place too and took the past minutes to become sure about it.

Comment: I see your edit there making i = i-1 where a row was deleted; however in my opinion this is less clear than using the natural logic of Excel to simply start at the bottom and move up. There is no particular reason here why it needs to start at 1, and therefore it is cleaner to simply use "For i = lastRow to 1 Step -1" instead of "For i = 1 to lastRow". Although I agree your method will prevent 'skipping rows'.

Comment: Your suggestion is of course, a more beautiful solution. In this case I thought about my beginnings of programming. It was easier for me to understand the program from the top to bottom.

Comment: if you want to be really fancy and efficient, you should use the autofilter and delete the rows in one go rather than looping.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to get rid of rows with *all* types of errors in column A, you could use the `SpecialCells` method to find and remove them in a single statement:

```
Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete
```